# Modifying Scala arguments in recursive method

Tags: scala, recursion, immutability

I'm trying to implement a recursive method in Scala and am running into mutability issues (I'm brand new to Scala):

```
def findMembersRecursive(path : String, members : Set[String]) : Unit = {
    val candidates : Set[String] = candidateService.getProspectiveCandidates(path)

    candidates.foreach { candidate =>
        if(candidate.endsWith("hello")) {
            members ++= candidate
        } else {
            findMembersRecursive(candidate, members)
        }
    }
}
```

So the idea is that as we execute recursively, this set of strings (`members`) grows.

Here it won't let me add `candidate` to `members` because `members` appears to be immutable. Any ideas as to how I could refactor the code to work recursively?

Comment: Why don't you make findMembersRecursive return members? Why do you want to keep 'members' as argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement this function this way:

```
def findMembersRecursive(path: String): Set[String] = 
  candidatesService
    .getProspectiveCandidates(path)
    .flatMap { 
      case candidate if candidate.endsWith("hello") => Set(candidate)
      case candidate => findMembersRecursive(candidate)
    }
```